# Using httplistener handle more concurrent request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Goal: To be able to handle thousands of request per second

Current Result: while the test code was at request 15k the http server had only processed about 3-400 request

My first iteration of this code I had set HTTP_HANDLER_THREADS to 2 where as after about 200 proccessed the server is overloaded and crashes.

I then up this number to 5 with similiar results.

I then up the number to 5000 and I got to around 800. This seems to me I am doing something very wrong because there is no way my system is running 5000 threads and based on running `top -H -p <pid>` I could see the thread pool and it did not open 5000 threads.

Very confused and would like help on how to adjust this to handle thousands of request

TestCase

```c#
class Program
    {

        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        private static int send_amount = 200000;

        private static int sent_request = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Parallel.For(0, send_amount, i =>
             {
                 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                     { "request", i.ToString() }
                 };

                 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                 var response = client.PostAsync("http://192.168.102.165:1990", content);

                 sent_request += 1;

                 Console.WriteLine($"Sent request {sent_request}/{send_amount}");
             });
        }
    }
```

Constants

```c#
internal class Constants
    {
        public static bool IsDebugMode = false;

        public const string PRODUCTION_IP = "192.168.102.165";
        public const string DEVELOPMENT_IP = "192.168.102.165";

        public const Int32 HTTP_PORT = 1990;
        public const Int32 HTTPS_PORT = 1990;

        public const Int32 HTTP_HANDLER_THREADS = 5000;

        public static string[] SERVER_BINDS
        {
            get
            {
                var server_binds = new string[]
                {
                    $"http://{(IsDebugMode ? DEVELOPMENT_IP : PRODUCTION_IP)}:{HTTP_PORT}/"
                };

                return server_binds;
            }
        }
    }
```

Http server class

```c#
internal class HTTPServer
    {
        private readonly ProcessDataDelegate handler;
        private readonly HttpListener listener;

        public HTTPServer(HttpListener listener, string[] prefixes, ProcessDataDelegate handler)
        {
            this.listener = listener;
            this.handler = handler;

            for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.Length; i++)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add(prefixes[i]);
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (listener.IsListening)
            {
                return;
            }

            listener.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < Constants.HTTP_HANDLER_THREADS; i++)
            {
                listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(ProcessRequestHandler);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (listener.IsListening)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void ProcessRequestHandler(Task<HttpListenerContext> result)
        {
            var context = result.Result;

            if (!listener.IsListening) return;

            //Start a new listener which will replace this
            listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(ProcessRequestHandler);

            //Read request
            var request = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

            //Prepare response
            var response_bytes = handler.Invoke(request);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = response_bytes.Length;

            var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
            output.WriteAsync(response_bytes, 0, response_bytes.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
    }
```

Program

```c#
class Program
    {

        private static Thread _console_thread;

        private static int request_amount = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitConsoleThread();
            InitHttpServer();
        }

        private static void InitHttpServer()
        {
            var http_listener = new HttpListener();

            var http_server = new HTTPServer.HTTPServer(http_listener, Constants.SERVER_BINDS, ProcessResponse);
            http_server.Start();
        }

        private static byte[] ProcessResponse(string response)
        {
            request_amount += 1;
            Console.WriteLine(request_amount);
            
            //Sleep was added here to simulate the code doing something
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            return new byte[0];
        }

        private static void InitConsoleThread()
        {
            _console_thread = new Thread(ConsoleLoop)
            {
                Name = "ConsoleThread"
            };

            _console_thread.Start();
        }

        private static void ConsoleLoop()
        {
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you given raw endpoint routing a try? It is super optimized, and might just suit your needs

Comment: `HttpListener` was badly written and not optimized. Upon .NET Core, please use Kestrel.

Comment: @TheGeneral I have not taken a look at it I do you have somewhere that could get me started in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at the hello world example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0 I am not sure if there is a template prebuilt for it, however its as easy as starting a new web api application removing everything and adding `app.UseRouting(); app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints..MapGet("/", async context => .... ); });`